# mysql conditional statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

i am facing a little problem in an sql query,

here is the query

```
SELECT events.event_id,
( SELECT favorite_events.event_id, 
        (CASE favorite_events.event_id WHEN NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
        FROM favorite_events 
        WHERE favorite_events.event_id = events.event_id 
) AS is_favorite
FROM events 
WHERE start_date = 2013-07-16
```

it is giving me "Operand should contain 1 column(s)
" error, please help!

Comment: Don't do this. Use a JOIN.

Comment: I'm asking this out of curiosity - did you perhaps google the error `Operand should contain 1 column(s)`?

Comment: yes, i tried, there were many queries like this, but i was unable to find as exact answer as below!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a JOIN, not a correlated subquery.

```
SELECT e.event_id,
       f.event_id IS NOT NULL AS is_favorite
FROM events e
LEFT JOIN favorite_events f
ON f.event_id = e.event_id
WHERE e.start_date = '2013-07-16'
```

Answer (score 2):

In the subquery you are selecting 2 columns. You can't rename 2 colums as `is_favorite`.

I assume, by looking at the query, you probably don't need the field `favorite_events.event_id`. Just remove that part.